# Disabling my onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 buttons, and I cant find out how to disable & enable them. Basically I have a timer, used for an animation. Whenever i press stop animation i want the timer to stop (this works) and i want the stop animation button to disable, and the start animation button to enable. I tried every syntax of html & jquery I saw, but it still doesn't seem to work... Can anyone help me out here?
I tried using jquery selectors, html selectors, .prop('disabled',false), .isDisabled,.disable and so on and so on. I'm out of ideas..

My html button code:

```
<input type="button" id="start" value="Start Animation"/>
<input type="button" id="stop" value="Stop Animation"/>
```

My js code:

```
var startinterval = setInterval(SliderPosition, 2000);
$("#start").attr('disabled','disabled');
$("#start").click(function(){startAnimation(1);});
$("#stop").click(function(){startAnimation(0);});
function startAnimation(bool) {
    if(bool == 0)
    {
        $("#stop").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#start").attr('disabled', false);
        clearInterval(startinterval);
    }
    else{
        $("#stop").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#start").attr('disabled','disabled');
        startinterval = setInterval(SliderPosition, 2000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `prop()` for this. If you are using `.attr()`, you need to complement using `.removeAttr()`:

```
var startinterval = setInterval(SliderPosition, 2000);
$("#start").prop('disabled', true);
$("#start").click(function(){startAnimation(1);});
$("#stop").click(function(){startAnimation(0);});
function startAnimation(bool) {
    if(bool == 0) {
        $("#stop").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#start").prop('disabled', false);
        clearInterval(startinterval);
    } else {
        $("#stop").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#start").prop('disabled', true);
        startinterval = setInterval(SliderPosition, 2000);
    }
}
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
// var startinterval = setInterval(SliderPosition, 2000);
$("#start").prop('disabled', true);
$("#start").click(function() {
  startAnimation(1);
});
$("#stop").click(function() {
  startAnimation(0);
});

function startAnimation(bool) {
  if (bool == 0) {
    $("#stop").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#start").prop('disabled', false);
    // clearInterval(startinterval);
  } else {
    $("#stop").prop('disabled', false);
    $("#start").prop('disabled', true);
    // startinterval = setInterval("", 2000);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="start" value="Start Animation" />
<input type="button" id="stop" value="Stop Animation" />
```

Comment: So this is one of the things I have already tried.  I used your code, and it doesn't do a thing on my button. I should have the correct selector though, because the onclick works just fine. With this code, I can also still press my buttons, and their onclicks still fire. I really don't get why this sample code doesn't work, because it should work..

Comment: @Runey Did you add jQuery? Lemme create a snippet for you and make it work.

Comment: @Runey The snippet works well. Check. Since `SliderPosition` is not included in the demo, I have commented it out. Kindly tell me if you see any errors in the console.

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff. I guess I need to have four eyes. `:)`

Comment: hmm yes the snippet indeed seems to work. I was able to fix the proble. For some reason i used an outdated jquery version (1.1) No idea how I managed to do that.. Stupid me. Thanks a lot for helping me out though, I always seem to get stuck on stupid problems like this ^^

Comment: @Runey Yeaaaah!!! Now I get it. `:P` I forgot to ask the version. `:)` So does it work?

Comment: Haha yea it works now :) Thanks a lot, i marked it as the answer!